# Как получить ответ json_encode

Tags: php

Всем добрый день.

Подскажите пожалуйста, какой структурой должна быть переменная что бы jsone_encode вернул вот так

```
{"result": {
    "message": "Запрос успешно обработан"
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Это может быть простой массив на php

```html
<?php

$array = [
    'result' => [
        'message' => "Запрос успешно обработан"
    ]
];

$json = json_encode($array);


?>
```

Comment: При выполнении вашего кода генерируется массив. Необходимо использовать константу [JSON_FORCE_OBJECT](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) вторым параметром для функции json_encode, либо создавать объекты stdClass.